# How to distinguish the meaning of 'come from' in a sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I am confused about the meaning of the below question

> Where do you come from?

When a person asks this question are they asking about where I originally come from (say from Brazil), or are they simply asking where I come from that specific day (say a suburb around the city)?

Comment: When you hear your non-native speakers ask *Where do you come from?* you should tell them that native speakers rarely say that. Natives ask *Where are you from?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is:

> Where are you **coming** from?

Then they are asking you where you're coming from *that specific day*.

On the other hand, if they ask one of the following:

> Where **are** you from?
>
> Where do you **come** from?

Then it refers to your *place of origin*.

Comment: "Where are you coming from?" can also mean "What emotional state are you in that would cause you to think that?" or "What reasoning leads you to think that?"